# How to associate an existing user to a site in a multisite setup programmatically

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

In a multisite setup, you can associate an existing user in the network to a site.  The standard wp_insert_user function doesn't seem to have the proper logic to handle.  How would I do this for multisite?

Also, is there a way to see if a given user is already associated with a particular site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking the code the create user, i found that that I can do:

```
$userdata = get_user_by('login', 'user1'); 
add_existing_user_to_blog( array( 'user_id' => $userdata->ID, 'role' => 'author'));
```

Fix: was missing closing )

Comment: The recommended function to use is now `add_user_to_blog()`: https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/add_user_to_blog

Answer (score 0):

You need to use :

```
add_user_to_blog( int $blog_id, int $user_id, string $role )
```

Example :

```
add_user_to_blog($blog->id, $user->ID, 'subscriber');
```

Source : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_to_blog/